# What academic researchers published very few scientific articles (say, less than twenty) but exerted large influences on their fields of study?

Tags: publications, science, academic-history

I find researchers and writers who published very little, yet were influential in their respective fields of study, interesting. A good example of such a researcher was the mathematician C. F. Gauss, whose motto was "Pauca sed matura" ("Few but ripe"). Authors who seemed to have adhered to a similar motto were Harper Lee, J. D. Salinger, and G. T. di Lampedusa.

What are some good examples of scientists and other academics who were not prolific, yet were nonetheless able to leave their mark?

Let's set the bar the for maximum number of publications at 20, so as to include more possible scientists as answers to this question

Comment: Here one may find a list of mathematicians similar to Gauss in terms of their publication output: - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867000/are-there-any-well-known-mathematicians-who-published-very-little

Comment: Not really a complete answer, but Ising comes to mind, or even Gödel.

Comment: Related to https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/151174/109931. Galois certainly, though he died so young he could not become an academic. Littrow is another.

Comment: Science/math, publications, and research were all very very different in process when Gauss was alive relative to the modern day.

Comment: @Jon Custer True, it may be good to restrict this question to scientists from a certain date onwards, from which time the scientific process was somewhat similar to ours'

Comment: I believe Ian Grojnowski is a good example, considering 10 papers in the 29 years since PhD.

Comment: For orientation, it might also be noted that, in pre-internet and pre-easy-typesetting times, the impact that people had on their fields was not at all measured in paper counts. A wonderful paper every few years was more than most people could hope for. And I don't think that people these days who produce 20 papers each year have 20 great ideas each year. Sure, maybe updates, which is fine, but math is not traditionally "experimental" in the sense of having worthwhile monthly reports on never-ending experiments.

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: I think it is being labeled as a "shopping question", but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/?_ga=2.238348805.482189275.1628586436-2039787068.1622442422) I personally don't think this should be closed as a shopping question.

Answer (score 6):

Gregor Mendel had only a small number of publications (in fact, really only one major publication, "Versuche über Pflanzenhybriden"—"Experiments on Plant Hybridization" in English), but he laid the groundwork for the modern understanding of genetics.

He was not influential in his own time; his work was, in fact, all but ignored when it was published in the 1860s.  Most of the leading biologists of the time, including Darwin, were unaware of Mendel's experiments.  However, in the early twentieth century, Mendel's work was rediscovered and duplicated, and since that time it has been incredibly influential.  Had his work on pea plant genetics gotten the attention it deserved at the time, he might have been able to continue his work; as it was, when he became abbot at St. Thomas's Abbey in Brno in 1867, he no longer had time to pursue his experiments himself.

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, Claude Shannon, who started the field of information theory.  Peter Higgs is another.

Answer (score 5):

Two mathematicians, both working in geometry/topology and both with <20 papers:

1. Andrew Casson has been extraordinarily influential, but only has 17 papers on MathScinet.  Much of his most important work (e.g. on the Casson invariant of homology 3-spheres) was written up and published by other people.
2. Steven Kerckhoff is also a very important mathematician.  MathScinet lists him as having 20 papers, but one of them is his thesis (which is not a real publication -- the main result was published in the journal Topology), so he has 19 "real" papers.

By the way, I didn't have to remove Casson's thesis since he did not have a PhD.  He did attend graduate school at the University of Liverpool, but his dislike for writing began early and he didn't write a thesis.

Comment: FYI, someone who wrote a well known monograph in 1992 on (an extension of) Casson's invariant graduated from the same high school I did, 4 years after I did -- a small and rural HS, at least then (the school since relocated and expanded). Your mention of Casson reminded me of [some comments of mine](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/21112/looking-for-copies-of-vasily-vasilovich-davydovs-mathematics-curriculum/21113#comment58414_21113) that I was thinking of deleting (not all under that question, but some of them) because of the (possibly) personal details of other people.

Comment: As far as I know, I am the only mathematician (or academic scientist more generally) to ever graduate from my high school.  This was back in 1998 and I don't follow it very carefully, but given how rough an area it is in I doubt this has changed.

Answer (score 4):

[Henry Moseley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Moseley) had a very brief career and [published only eight papers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/228365) before being killed during the Battle of Gallipoli in 1915. In Isaac Asimov's estimation, "his death might well have been the most costly single death of the War to mankind generally." However, the works Moseley did complete included pioneering applications of X-ray spectroscopy in physics that, among other things, established the concept of atomic number as a non-arbitrary quantity, refined our understanding of atomic structure, and let him predict the existence of several new elements.

Answer (score 2):

Though Gauss published little in his lifetime, he *wrote* [quite a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Writings), and many of his writings have been subsequently published and are now publicly available --- his  are quite substantial.  In any case, an obvious place to look would be major mathematicians who died young.  For example, [Évariste Galois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois) made a major contribution to abstract algebra and then died in a duel at the age of twenty, so consequently his published output was small, despite its large impact.

Answer (score 1):

Jack Silver had a tremendous influence on set theory but published only 11 papers. (MathSciNet lists 14, but one is his thesis and two are solutions of problems in the American Mathematical Monthly.) His contributions include the theory of indiscernibles for the constructible universe (later named 0^#), the theorem that the generalized continuum hypothesis (GCH) cannot first fail at a singular cardinal of uncountable cofinality, the "countable vs. perfect" dichotomy for co-analytic equivalence relations, the proof that GCH holds in the model of sets constructible from a normal measure, and the proof that analytic sets have the Ramsey property. Each of these has been the foundation for a great deal of continuing research.